# Adding an image results to GenerateResource Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, frameworks, resources

I was working with background images in Visual Basic 2010 and successfully debugged the program during the first tries. However, after experimenting with some images using my Resources, my project messed up giving me this error:

> Error 1   The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A
>   generic error occurred in GDI+.    at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream
>   stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo
>   si, StreamingContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, _*BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceWriter.WriteValue(ResourceTypeCode typeCode,
>   Object value, BinaryWriter writer, IFormatter objFormatter)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Generate()    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Close()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo
>   reader, IResourceWriter writer)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo
>   reader, String filename)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile,
>   String outFileOrDir)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log,
>   ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean
>   sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String
>   resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean
>   publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory) 
>   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper
>   log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs,
>   Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String
>   resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean
>   publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory) 
>   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d*_20.MoveNext() WindowsApplication1

I also tried using Visual Studio 2012 then I added an image to Form's background image but it gives me the same error as I enter the debug mode. I can't work with images right now using the 2 versions of my Visual Basic.

Comment: Friend of mine has the same problem; one image seems to be the cause. Removing it allowed us to compile, but it's a resource his app needs.
Re-compiling also works.